# I used Naive Bayes Classifier, but now I want to use SVM classifier, what to do?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, svm

I am classifying text with 2 categories. One is imperatives, and the other one is non-imperatives. I prepared my text in the way Naive Bayes Classifier needs. But, now, I also need to use SVM. What should I do here? (I need to classify the text and calculate the accuracy, too.)Thank you for reading and trying to answering my questions.

```
all_words_list = [word for (sent, cat) in train for word in sent]
all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words_list)
word_items = all_words.most_common(1000)
word_features = [word for (word, count) in word_items]

def document_features(document, word_features):
    document_words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for word in word_features:
        features['contains({})'.format(word)] = (word in document_words)
    return features

 featuresets = [(document_features(d, word_features), c) for (d, c) in 
 train]

train_set, test_set = featuresets[360:], featuresets[:360]
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
print (nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_set))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest first divide your dataset in train and test properly

`X` contains feature variable and `Y` contains response variable and we are splitting it in 70%-30%

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=101,test_size=0.3)
```

than

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics
#on sklearn docs you can find more about SVM parameters
model = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf',C=10000.0,gamma = 'auto')
model = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Accuracy is ', round(metrics.accuracy_score(model.predict(X_test),y_test),2))
```

Comment: in this case, x= sentence, y=label (imperatives or non-imperatives)?

Comment: I don't understand what x and y mean here. I look forward to your reply. Thank you so much.

Comment: my featureset looks like this:

Comment: ({'contains(being)': False, 'contains(check)': False, 'contains(chicken)': False, 'contains(koothrappali)': False, 'contains(shut)': False....  }, 'imp')

Comment: what should I define X and Y from the featureset?

Comment: Yes Zong, X is sentence and y is label. In this case, it is getting the test set from the whole set of inputs. You dont need to prepare a distinct test set. I would recommend using a 10fold CrossValidation to avoid overfitting. You can refer to it at: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html